# SAP Logon 760 via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, sap-gui

since the SAP update my vba application fails to connect to the sap system.
My previous code does not work anymore. I guess it is because of the new subfolder. The subfolder "All Urt SAP Systems" and "01 Test System" did not exist in the past.

However this code worked in the past without the new subfolders:

```
Set rotentry = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set App = rotentry.GetScriptingEngine
App.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set Connection = App.OpenConnection("TE1 (Test - Development System)")  '<-- Here comes the error
Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
```

Does anybody know what I am missing here? I tried a few SAP forums without success.

I am getting the following error message:

```
SAP Logon connection entry not found
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error message? what's the error and what line does it occur on?

Comment: Maybe if you change `App.Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to `True`, you'll get an interactive message that gives you a clue

Comment: Sorry my bad, forgot the error message. I edited my question.

Comment: In these situations, I would find the connection collection and enumerate through it and see what named connecitons the API thinks exist. This means, enable a breakpoint on the line that fails then use object browser (F2) to inspect the `App` variable at runtime and see what connections it think exists.

Comment: You may also be able to connect by ordinal instead of name: `Set Connection = App.OpenConnection(0)`

Comment: Here's some other sample code that connects by ordinal: https://intellipaat.com/community/6985/excel-vba-connecting-to-sap-what-type-of-object-is-returned-by-getobject-sapgui the issue might be as simple as there being an extra space in the connection name that you can't see

Comment: If I guess clearly your screenshot, there is a missing space at the end of the connection string, between "System" and ")", it should be `Set Connection = App.OpenConnection("TE1 (Test - Development System )"`.

Comment: @SandraRossi I think you nailed it :)

Comment: Nah the space is not missing. It just looks that way. In the past (withouth the subfolders)  it worked and this is just a sample I edited :-)

Comment: I don't have any problem with my 7.60, whatever the entry is in subfolders or not. Did you try with simple names for the logon entry, like "A", to see if it works? And what if you move the logon entry at the root? The last solution is to check with SAP if there's a bug in SAP GUI.

Comment: I tryed the `App.OpenConnection(0)` and it worked, so as @Sandra Rossi stated it was not the fault of the sub folders. I checked the object browser and found a way to enumerate through the collection and display the connection names. The internal names for the connections were slightly different than the dispalyed names. Thanks for the help :-) it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "True":

```
Set Connection = App.OpenConnection("TE1 (Test - Development System)",True)
```

If you still get the error try to comment `App.Application.DisplayAlerts = False` this part and try it again.